# How to Populate values to textboxes dynamically on Picklist Selection Change in Standard page layout

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, dynamic

Is it possible to populate values in textboxes(fields of object) dynamically on Pick list
selection change in Standard page layout's edit screen.

Something like that if Picklist's value = "AB" then
Field A's value = A AND 
Field B's value = B

And if Picklist's value = "CD" then
Field A's value = C AND 
Field B's value = D

like Selected index change event of .Net in which page get reload to fill the values.

is it possible in Salesforce Standard page layout's edit screen? if yes then please suggest me the way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot easily do this in the standard layout.  You could accomplish the same end result, you could use workflows to have the text field values be updated dependent on the picklist value, but this would not happen until the record was saved.  It would not dynamically update the text fields on the edit page as you changed the picklist field.

If you needed it to be dynamic and update the text fields on the change of the picklist field, then you would need to use Visualforce.

Here is an example of this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015597/display-fields-based-on-selection-on-a-picklist-selection

Comment: @How about using the javascript in home page component ?

Comment: yes, but I need to put the values from other object to populate. will javascript work in this scenario?

Comment: @Mohith, yes that would work, but just assuming that if he's looking to do it on the standard layout, that VF is more simple and easy then JS in a homepage component.  But yes, you are right, that would be possible.

Comment: @Saam, I don't understand, the question doesnt mention other objects at all.  Could you update your question to describe what you are trying to do with other objects

Comment: @SF_Ninja Yes homepage component is not reliable too.But if user is looking for quick fix this approach may fit in.

Comment: Correct, although I have used it, I think of JS in home page components as 'Hackish' and try to avoid it if I can.  Could also break at any time with SF updates

Comment: @SF_Ninja : I means I want to query other objects also to fill the values of input field. When user choose value from Picklist, I will query another Custom object to get the interest value based on picklist's selected value. User can owerwrite this value. Well I am going to use another way.

Comment: If that is the case then you definitely need to use VF and Apex.  You might want to update your question to reflect what your really looking for also.

Comment: This Q&A needs a bit of a refresh to bring it into the Lightning era.