# Trigger to Pull related contact designation on Task page when tesk create or edit

Tags: apex, triggercontext, trigger

I have a requirement. Contact related to Task, I need to pull his functional role ( custom field) on Activity page layout. So whenever I create or edit an activity and relate with ant contact so his/her functional role should populate automatic.

Please help! How can I achieve it? I tried formula field but unable to get. I tried through trigger but  I tried through trigger but it is not working neither on new task nor while I update the task.

Please find below code:

```
trigger updatefunctionalroletxt on Task (before insert, before update) {

Map<ID,String> confunrole = new Map<ID,String>();
List<Task> conTasks = new List<Task>();


for (Task e : trigger.new) {

    if (e.whoID!= null && (String.valueOf(e.whoID)).startsWith('003'))  {

        if (trigger.isInsert || (trigger.isUpdate && e.WhoID != trigger.oldMap.get(e.id).WhoID)) {
            confunrole.put(e.whoID,'');
            conTasks.add(e);
        }
    }
}

for (contact con : [SELECT Functional_Role__c FROM contact WHERE ID IN :confunrole.keySet()]) {
    confunrole.put(con.id,con.Functional_Role__c);
}
// Update the contact functional role field on the Task with the relevant value
for (Task e : trigger.new) {
    e.functional_role__c = confunrole.get(e.whoID);
}
}
```

Kindly help to write a correct trigger.

Comment: Your trigger context is before you need to change it to after, because you won't be able to get record Id in after insert

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger seems to be fine!
You can not do that while you are updating a record (aprat from dependent picklist) I suggest you use a VF page for your requirement.

[Here is a similar answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18885/how-to-populate-values-to-textboxes-dynamically-on-picklist-selection-change-in)

Comment: Hi, This trigger is not working event with new records.

Comment: Getting error : Execute Anonymous Error Line: 1, Column: 0 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'trigger'

Comment: Can paste your code as in what you are trying to Insert or Update? @Russelbaker1

Comment: Code already available in above question. @d_k

Comment: No I meant what are you trying to do in Execute anonymous that's what I want to see

Comment: Same code I tried to execute. also this code saved successfully but not working. not populating contact functional role on task functional role field.

Comment: Hi, Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Have you tried putting a debug statement and checking if you are actually getting any value?

Comment: Yes, I am not getting any value. it seems trigger is not working. Some thing is missing in trigger code. can you please check the code and let me know where I am doing wrong. @d_k

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41766/discussion-between-d-k-and-russel-baker-1).

Comment: It's not working.